# I can't find information with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i want to do a web-scraping of a url, but when i use BeautifulSoup some informations i'm looking is not found, but they are in the original html. if print(html_page), i have all information i need, but when it comes out the output, does not have the information, when i try to search directly on the html_page this error happens:

```
word = html_page  
word.find('name="produto-stock"')               
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'
```

#### my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.maze.com.br/produto/tenis-puma-suede-classic-azul-marinho/4513515'

res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all(text=True)

output = ''
blacklist = [
    'noscript',
    'header',
    'html',
    'meta',
    'head', 
    'input',
    'script',

]

for t in text:
    if t.parent.name not in blacklist:
        output += '{} '.format(t)
    
word = output
word.find('produto-stock')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why enclose it in quotes, remove them :-(

```
word = html_page
word.find("produto-stock")
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this change, but the error still happens: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'